# How to use "indexOf" in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, indexof

Hi I am usin Angular and I am struggling for an issue.
I would like to know How to use "indexOf()" method on a array which has two or more fields.
Here is my code:

My array:

```
[
{
  "id":1,
  "name": "stuff",
  "surname": "stuff"
},
{
  "id":2,
  "name": "stuff",
  "surname": "stuff"
},
{
  "id":3,
  "name": "stuff",
  "surname": "stuff"
}
]
```

in my angular Code I would like to a user type a certain id from the template(in the form) and check if the corresponding user exists in my array.
my angular code is:

```
      <form #formValue="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClick(formValue)">
             <div class="form-group">
               <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Identifiant du challenge</label>
               <input type="text" name="_id" #_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="this.user._id" 
                 class="form-control"  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" 
                 placeholder="identifiant">
               
             </div>
             
              
             <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </form>
```

in my *.ts file I have a method that I perform on the submit event named "onClick"
look at my ts file:

```
 onClick(form: NgForm){
    this.getUsers(form.value._id)
  }

// get users method

 getUsers(id: String){
     return this._http.get<any[]>(this.url + 'getAllChallenge').subscribe(
         (users)=>{
             this.users=users;

             this.checkExist= this.users.indexOf(id)
              if(this.checkExist==-1){
                  alert("this id you typed doesn't exist in our array")
               }
               else{

                  /* here is my issue. this alert if is always printed enven 
                     If I type 1,2 or 3(an 
                     existing id)*/

                  alert("this Id exist")
                 }
          
                  
              } 
     );
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you don't.

The function you want to use is [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

You give it a function which should return true or false based on whatever you want. It will then return the first element that matches, or `undefined` if no elements do. So, if you get a match, it exists, otherwise, it doesn't. You don't have to explicitly cast to a Boolean, but you can.

```
this.checkExist = Boolean(this.users.find(user => user.id === id));
```

This is also a [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method which returns the index instead of the object itself if you'd prefer that, but if you're using it as a Boolean, using `find()` will be safer (since you won't have to check for `!== -1`).

Answer (score 2):

If you passed the object to getUsers() function, you could actually do that.
I don't know if it is possible in Angular.

```
a={}
b={}
c=[a,b]
c.indexOf(b) // = 1
```

Otherwise use the find() method as suggested by others.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `findIndex()`

```js
var arr = [
{
  "id":1,
  "name": "stuff",
  "surname": "stuff"
},
{
  "id":2,
  "name": "stuff",
  "surname": "stuff"
},
{
  "id":3,
  "name": "stuff",
  "surname": "stuff"
}
]

let index = arr.findIndex((obj) => {
  return obj.id == 2
})
console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` find index of a element in array. For ex.:

```js
[1,2,3].indexOf(1); // 0
```

But if you want to search for element with a property (and find *index* in array) you can use `findIndex`:

```js
this.users.findIndex(u => u.id === id);
```